# Algorithm to find extrema of a function?

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms, numerical-algorithms

What are some simple algorithms that find the maximum of a function in a certain domain?

The function $f$ is guaranteed to have 1 maximum and no other turning points between $a$ and $b$, how can I find out what the value of this maximum is without knowing anything about the function? I can only query what $f(x)$ is for some $x$. How can I eventually approximate the $x$ for which the function has its maximum?

Comment: Do you know the order of the curve ?

Comment: @t123 all I can do is query what $f(x)$ is for a certain $x$. It could be anything, not necessarily a polynomial.

Comment: What do you mean by "no turning points"?  Do you mean it is increasing, then decreasing?  If so, try a variant on binary search.

Comment: @D.W. at the moment I'm thinking that I take the midpoint between the two highest values found so far

Comment: Still not clear what you mean by "no turning points", so it's hard to know how to answer your question.

Comment: @D.W. if $a\leq u<v\leq m$ and $m$ is the x-coordinate of the maximum then $f(u)<f(v)$. Similarly if $m\leq u<v\leq b$ then $f(u)>f(v)$.

Comment: Great.  Please edit the question to incorporate all information into the question, so the question reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time, and so people don't need to read the comments to understand what you are asking.  Thank you!

Comment: Is the function simply a black box or is an there an analytic form for f(x)?

Comment: @csTheoryBeginner I don't know what an analytic form is, but the function seems to me to be a black box apart from the information given about the fact there's only one turning point.

Comment: @theonlygusti - is the function continuous? If so, according to wikipedia, then it is either a local minima or maxima. Since there is only 1 turning point, then that point has to be one of these. In which case you could use gradient based methods (gradient descent & or ascent) to figure out the maximum.

Comment: @csTheoryBeginner but gradient ascent/descent relies on knowing the function's gradients at certain points.

Comment: @theonlygusti - If you are convinced that the gradient method would have been useful if the gradient information was available, then one could try  to approximate it. Alternatively, have you looked at Nelder-Mead algorithm (http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Nelder-Mead_algorithm) and its relatives?